# How to reduce/transform an array of objects to result in the aggregate sum of each property (lodash ideally)

Tags: functional-programming, lodash, reduce

I have an array of nutrition object that look something like this:

```
[
  {
    calories: {total: 0, fat: 0},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 0, retinol: 0}, b6: 0, c: 0},
    fats: {total: 0},
    minerals: {calcium: 0}
  },
  {
    calories: {total: 150, fat: 40},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 100}, b6: 30, c: 200},
    fats: {total: 3}
  },
  {
    calories: {total: 100, fat: 60},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 120, retinol: 10}, b6: 0, c: 200},
    minerals: {calcium: 20}
  }
]
```

Note that I have added a 0 filled object so that no properties are null or undefined; not all properties exist on subsequent objects; and that this is a pretty deep object (i.e. obj.vitamins.a.total)

the result should be

```
{
  calories: {total: 250, fat: 100},
  vitamins: {a: {total: 220, retinol: 10}, b6: 30, c: 400},
  fats: {total: 3},
  minerals: {calcium: 20}
}
```

I'm aware of `lodash`'s `_.reduce()` and `_.transform()` functions, but I'm not sure how to access properties on the `accumulator`. **How can I achieve the desired result, ideally using functional programming and lodash.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although [Ori Drori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236337/how-to-reduce-transform-an-array-of-objects-to-result-in-the-aggregate-sum-of-ea#answer-42237403) already specified the direction of using [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith), his usage lies in creating a recursive function that recursively calls `mergeWith`. This solution disregards the fact that `mergeWith` is by nature a recursive merge wherein the customizer would only transform the resulting value if it returns any value that is not `undefined`. Additionally, another problem is that `mergeWith` mutates the first object argument, which might not be ideal in cases where you want to retain the state of the source objects.

The solution below uses [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with `mergeWith` instead of wrapping it in a [spread](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread), you can decide to switch it to `spread` depending on your taste. To solve the problem of source object mutation, we supply an empty object as the first argument and then concatenate it with the rest of the source objects. Lastly, we concatenate the customizer function that returns the sum of the arguments if `value` is a number.

```
var result = _.mergeWith.apply(
  null, 
  [{}].concat(source).concat(function(value, src) {
    if(_.isNumber(value)) {
      return value + src;
    }
  })
);
```

```js
var source = [
  {
    calories: {total: 0, fat: 0},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 0, retinol: 0}, b6: 0, c: 0},
    fats: {total: 0},
    minerals: {calcium: 0}
  },
  {
    calories: {total: 150, fat: 40},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 100}, b6: 30, c: 200},
    fats: {total: 3}
  },
  {
    calories: {total: 100, fat: 60},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 120, retinol: 10}, b6: 0, c: 200},
    minerals: {calcium: 20}
  }
];

var result = _.mergeWith.apply(
  null, 
  [{}].concat(source).concat(function(value, src) {
    if(_.isNumber(value)) {
      return value + src;
    }
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
body>div {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: very elegant. Thank you

Comment: Nice. Good to know about the inherent excursiveness  of `_.mergeWith()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `_.mergeWith()`. I'm using `_.spread()` to create a `_.mergeWith()` that can handle an array instead of individual paramaters.

```js
var data = [{"calories":{"total":0,"fat":0},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":0,"retinol":0},"b6":0,"c":0},"fats":{"total":0},"minerals":{"calcium":0}},{"calories":{"total":150,"fat":40},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":100},"b6":30,"c":200},"fats":{"total":3}},{"calories":{"total":100,"fat":60},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":120,"retinol":10},"b6":0,"c":200},"minerals":{"calcium":20}}];

var mergeWith = _.spread(_.mergeWith);

function deepMerge(objs) {
  var args = [{}].concat(objs, function(objValue, srcValue) {
      if(_.isNumber(objValue)) {
        return objValue + srcValue;
      }
    });
  
  return mergeWith(args);
}

var result = deepMerge(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The ES6 version using the spread syntax:

```js
var data = [{"calories":{"total":0,"fat":0},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":0,"retinol":0},"b6":0,"c":0},"fats":{"total":0},"minerals":{"calcium":0}},{"calories":{"total":150,"fat":40},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":100},"b6":30,"c":200},"fats":{"total":3}},{"calories":{"total":100,"fat":60},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":120,"retinol":10},"b6":0,"c":200},"minerals":{"calcium":20}}];

function deepMerge(objs) {
  return _.mergeWith({}, ...objs, (objValue, srcValue) => {
    if (_.isNumber(objValue)) {
      return objValue + srcValue;
    }
  });
}

var result = deepMerge(data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As per [@naomik's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236337/how-to-reduce-transform-an-array-of-objects-to-result-in-the-aggregate-sum-of-ea/42237403#comment71634546_42237403), we can also extract the customizer to be an external method, so you can decide how exactly non object values are merged.

```js
var data = [{"calories":{"total":0,"fat":0},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":0,"retinol":0},"b6":0,"c":0},"fats":{"total":0},"minerals":{"calcium":0}},{"calories":{"total":150,"fat":40},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":100},"b6":30,"c":200},"fats":{"total":3}},{"calories":{"total":100,"fat":60},"vitamins":{"a":{"total":120,"retinol":10},"b6":0,"c":200},"minerals":{"calcium":20}}];

var mergeWith = _.spread(_.mergeWith);

function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if(_.isNumber(objValue)) {
    return objValue + srcValue;
  }
}

function deepMerge(objs, customizer) {
  var args = [{}].concat(objs, function(objValue, srcValue) {
      return customizer(objValue, srcValue);
    });
  
  return mergeWith(args);
}

var result = deepMerge(data, customizer);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe make `deepMerge` accept the combining function as a parameter? That would change `if (_.isNumber(objValue)) { ... }` to `else return f(objValue, srcValue)` – this would allow `f` to control how the terms are combined, making `deepMerge` more reusable

Comment: Otherwise good answer – much better than I could've imagined possible using Lodash.

Comment: @naomik - good idea. I've added another option with an external customizer.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. I thought customizers may be part of the solution, but didn't understand them from the lodash documentation.  Ori's solution seems more readable, elegant, and more easily convertible to typescript.

Comment: @NateMay the word "customizer" is just the name of a parameter that accepts a function.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you an answer that gets its inspiration from [Monoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). Without getting too dense into category theory, you need two things for a Monoid to work

- some value that represents the *empty* (or *neutral*) of your Monoid type
- and some function that combines two Monoids of your type together

---

**The Sum Monoid**

For starters, let's look at the `Sum` Monoid. There a countless ways you could implement this in JavaScript, but we'll just look at this one so you can get a rough idea

```js
const Sum = x => ({
  constructor: Sum,
  value: x,
  concat: ({value:y}) => Sum(x + y),
  fold: f => f (x)
})

Sum.empty = Sum(0)

Sum(3).concat(Sum(4)).fold(x => console.log(x))                // 7
Sum(3).concat(Sum(4)).concat(Sum(9)).fold(x => console.log(x)) // 16
```

---

**Next level monoid**

Using the `Sum` monoid, we can easily combine numbers, but what if our data was more complex? For example, what if our data was an object?

Imagine we have `x` and `y` and wish to combine them sensibly

```
let x = SumObject({ a: Sum(1), b: Sum(2) })
let y = SumObject({ b: Sum(3), c: Sum(4) })

x.concat(y)
// => SumObject({ a: Sum(1), b: Sum(5), c: Sum(4) })
```

That sure would be great! Let's implement the `SumObject` monoid now – Sorry, I couldn't really think of a better name for it!

```
const SumObject = x => ({
  constructor: SumObject,
  value: x,
  concat: ({value:y}) => {
    return SumObject(Object.keys(y).reduce((acc, k) => {
      if (acc[k] === undefined)
        return Object.assign(acc, { [k]: y[k] })
      else
        return Object.assign(acc, { [k]: acc[k].concat(y[k]) })
    }, Object.assign({}, x)))
  },
  fold: f => f(x)
})

SumObject.empty = SumObject({})
```

Holy smokes ! That one was a little tougher, but I hope you can see it. Notice the **bolded** code. Our implementation of `SumObject` assumes that the property *values* will be monoids, too – meaning the values will have a `.concat` method.

---

**Let's get into shape !**

In order for monoids to work with your data, we'll need to convert your primtive `Object` and `Number` types into the corresponding Monoid type.

Lastly, in order to get your answer out in the primitive type, we'll have to convert from the Monoid type *back* to the primitive type.

If all goes well, the resulting expression will look something like this

```
sumToPrimitive(data.map(x =>
  primitiveToSum(x)).reduce((acc, x) =>
    acc.concat(x), SumObject.empty))
```

Let's make the function that converts primitives to the Monoid type now

```
const primitiveToSum = x => {
  switch (x.constructor) {
    case Object:
      return SumObject(Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, k) =>
        Object.assign(acc, { [k]: primitiveToSum(x[k]) }), {}))
    case Number:
      return Sum(x)
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported type: ${x}`)
  }
}
```

Then we'll make one the converts the Monoid back to a primitive

```
const sumToPrimitive = x => {
  switch (x.constructor) {
    case SumObject:
      return x.fold(x =>
        Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, k) =>
          Object.assign(acc, { [k]: sumToPrimitive(x[k]) }), {}))
    case Sum:
      return x.fold(identity)
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported type: ${x}`)
  }
}
```

---

***"So that's it?"***

Well, because you're supporting *nested* objects, it's a little bit messy, but that's really the best we can do, I'm afraid. If you were willing to limit the data to flat objects, things would be a lot cleaner.

Nevertheless, let's see it all working

```js
const SumObject = x => ({
  constructor: SumObject,
  value: x,
  concat: ({value:y}) => {
    return SumObject(Object.keys(y).reduce((acc, k) => {
      if (acc[k] === undefined)
        return Object.assign(acc, { [k]: y[k] })
      else
        return Object.assign(acc, { [k]: acc[k].concat(y[k]) })
    }, Object.assign({}, x)))
  },
  fold: f => f(x)
})

SumObject.empty = SumObject({})

const Sum = x => ({
  constructor: Sum,
  value: x,
  concat: ({value:y}) => Sum(x + y),
  fold: f => f (x)
})

Sum.empty = Sum(0)

const primitiveToSum = x => {
  switch (x.constructor) {
    case Object:
      return SumObject(Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, k) =>
        Object.assign(acc, { [k]: primitiveToSum(x[k]) }), {}))
    case Number:
      return Sum(x)
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported type: ${x}`)
  }
}

const sumToPrimitive = x => {
  switch (x.constructor) {
    case SumObject:
      return x.fold(x =>
        Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, k) =>
          Object.assign(acc, { [k]: sumToPrimitive(x[k]) }), {}))
    case Sum:
      return x.fold(identity)
    default:
      throw Error(`unsupported type: ${x}`)
  }
}

const identity = x => x

const data = [
  {
    calories: {total: 0, fat: 0},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 0, retinol: 0}, b6: 0, c: 0},
    fats: {total: 0},
    minerals: {calcium: 0}
  },
  {
    calories: {total: 150, fat: 40},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 100}, b6: 30, c: 200},
    fats: {total: 3}
  },
  {
    calories: {total: 100, fat: 60},
    vitamins: {a: {total: 120, retinol: 10}, b6: 0, c: 200},
    minerals: {calcium: 20}
  }
]

const result = sumToPrimitive(data.map(x =>
  primitiveToSum(x)).reduce((acc, x) =>
    acc.concat(x), SumObject.empty))

console.log(result)
```

---

**Output**

```
{ calories: { total: 250, fat: 100 },
  vitamins: { a: { total: 220, retinol: 10 }, b6: 30, c: 400 },
  fats: { total: 3 },
  minerals: { calcium: 20 } }
```

---

**Remarks**

Monoids are a great interface for maintaining a **generic**, reusable way to combine terms - this is what functional programming is all about. However, due to the complicated nested of your data (and native JavaScript's lack of custom types), more manual coding is asked of you up front.

I can't imagine what a Lodash solution would look like – but what I can tell you is that it will throw generics and reusability out the window – especially given the structure of your data.

Comment: I'm trying to follow some course on Category Theory myself, and honestly I really thought I recognised a Functor in the 'structuring' of the data structure (which is a product type).  I was slightly surprised to not find an `fmap` in your answer, while this is, imho, what the `spread`/`merge` looks like.

Comment: @xtofl I'd love for you to explain a little further. I'm a novice in category theory, so it's probable the answer could be improved by someone that knows more than me ^_^

Comment: Being a novice myself... I thought a `Functor` can define how to construct a datatype from values (in this case a dict-of-dicts), and how to apply a function to them (`Functor.fmap(data, f)`).  Your monoidal function should be the `f` in this equation.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing this with Ramda, in pointfree fashion, but OP requested in Lodash, so here we go, simple solution with recursion :

```js
let data = [{calories: {total: 0, fat: 0},vitamins: {a: {total: 0, retinol: 0}, b6: 0, c: 0},fats: {total: 0},minerals: {calcium: 0}},{calories: {total: 150, fat: 40},vitamins: {a: {total: 100}, b6: 30, c: 200},fats: {total: 3}},{calories: {total: 100, fat: 60},vitamins: {a: {total: 120, retinol: 10}, b6: 0, c: 200},minerals: {calcium: 20}}];

        const recursor = result => (value, key) => {
            if ( _.isNumber(value) ) {
                result[key] = ((result[key] || (result[key] = 0)) + value);
                return result[key];
            } else {
                return  _.mapValues(value, recursor(result[key] || (result[key] = {}) ));
            }
        }

        const reducer = (result, value, key) => _.mapValues(value, recursor(result));

        let final = _.transform(data, reducer, {});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```